# Teechart linechart ,if add string , bottom axis label will change ,C#

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

```
  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line lin = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();   
  lin.Add(20, 0.017,"OA");
  lin.Marks.Visible = true;
  chart.Series.Add(lin);
  chart.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = 10;
  chart.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = 40;
```

will show
[A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Q0q.png)

but the result I want is picture B
[B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr0UX.png)

When I add text,I  want bottom axis label will not change.

How to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set bottom axis labels to display values like this:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.Value;
```